# get no result when running query from text file to fetch data from my table using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, html, text

I am trying to query some data from my table in mysql by reading a txt file in php, so far, I have the data pulling out of the txt file,but get no result

below is my code:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";

$dbutilisateur = "root";

$dbpasse = "";

$dbnom = "citweb";


$conn = new mysqli( $dbhost , $dbutilisateur, $dbpasse , $dbnom);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


   $handle = fopen("List.txt", "r");
   if ($handle) {
   while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
      $buffer = str_replace("\n", "", $buffer);
     if (preg_match('/(?<=\:).*/', $buffer, $group)) {
         $match = trim($group[0] ); // remove the space
         var_dump($match);                   

     }
}
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM servers
          WHERE cpu_manufacturer = $match";  


         var_dump ($sql);     
          $result = $conn->query($sql);

          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "cpu_manufacturer: " . $row["cpu_manufacturer"]. "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }


if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
$conn->close();
}
```

Below is the content of text file:

```
   cpu_manufacturer: AMD
   cpu_freq (GHz): 333
   cpu_model: Xeon E3-1230v2
   ram(GB): 256
   operating_system: Linux(CentOS)
   hdd_type: SSD
   hdd_capacity(GB):300
    Server Location: usa
```

below is the result that I get so far when using var_dump:

```
string(3) "AMD" string(3) "333" string(14) "Xeon E3-1230v2" string(3) "256" 
string(13) "Linux(CentOS)" string(3) "SSD" string(3) "300" string(3) "usa" 
string(64) "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE cpu_manufacturer = usa"
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp1\htdocs\fetchservers\index2.php on line 42

So nothing is in `$result->num_rows` it is less than zero...

Comment: It's not that `$result->num_rows` is less than zero. The problem is that `$result` is not a valid object. Probably some error in the query - table or column name. Also comparing strings without quotes and escaping is not a good idea.

Comment: String values need to be enclosed in quotes: `WHERE cpu_manufacturer = 'usa'`. I strongly recommend you use a prepared statement to bind `$match` to the query.

Comment: By the way, you're misinterpreting the error message. "Trying to get property of non-object" does not mean `$result->num_rows` is less than zero, it means `$result` is not an object. That means `$conn->query($sql)` is not returning a `mysqli_result` object, which means the query in `$sql` failed to execute. If that happens, check `$conn->error` to see what's wrong with the query.

Comment: @rickdenhaan , you're right on the error . I think my query is the issue as it returns nothing. Also I checked with $conn->error and got Unknown column 'usa' in 'where clause' . but my column is cpu_manufacturer not server location column. How can I get specific value like AMD from cpu_manufacturer ?

Comment: @TodorSimeonov I put trigger_error to see what's the error and got : Unknown column 'usa' in 'where clause'     Also I noticed $match takes the last string which is "usa" while I am comapring cpu_manufacturer!

Comment: By adding a prepared statement , my query is working now! however I can just extract the last string from my text file. How can I access to other strings's values ?